# Direct Table & Lookup Table

Tags: image, image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

How to measure memory size of an image in direct coding 24-bit RGB color model & in 24-bit 256-entry loop-up table representation. For example: Given an image of resolution 800*600. how much spaces are required to save the image using direct coding and look-up table.

Comment: Your question is being downvoted because it is very vague. And because it has bad formatting and grammar. Try at least to specify image format (grayscale, RGB, RGBA), image depth (8-bit, 16-bit), and, of course, what do you _exactly_ mean by "look-up table encoding".

Comment: Now, I have updated my question.

Comment: Now here is your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a regular 24-bit RGB representation most probably you just have to multiply the number of pixel on number of bytes per pixel. 24 bits = 3 bytes, so the size is 800 * 600 * 3 bytes = 1440000 bytes ≈ 1.37 MiB. In some cases you may have rows of an image aligned on some boundary in memory, usually 4 or 8 or 32 bytes.  But since 800 is divisible by 32, this will not change anything, still 1.37 MiB.

Now, for a look-up table, you have 1 byte per pixel, since you have only to address one entry in the table. This yields 800 * 600 * 1 = 480000 bytes ≈ 0.46 MiB. Plus the table itself: 256 colors, 24 bits (3 bytes) each - 256 * 3 = 768 bytes. Negligible comparing to the size of the image.